# If a man "was pressured… to inform against his own friend" did he actually do it?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Example

> He was pressured by the FBI to inform against his own friend.

This means that the FBI pressured him, AND he ACTUALLY DID inform against his own friend. Right?

Then, what do you say if you don't want to refer to the part of whether he did actually inform his own friend or not?

In another words, what do you say
only

> The FBI pressured him and said to him 'You'd better tell us about your friends.'

Starting with "He was pressured by the FBI..." without referring to whether he actually did so or not.

Comment: The initial premise is incorrect. He was pressured.  It does not follow that he informed. Your question needs more clarity.

Comment: Your original example might imply that he did inform, but does not entail this. Consider "He was pressured by the FBI to inform against his own friend, but refused to do so."

Comment: as an addendum to @theawesomeatom 's answer pointing out that the initial sentence has the meaning you want, in order for the first sentence to imply that he did give in, it would have to be changed to something like "He was pressured by the FBI into informing on his own friend" (informing on sounds more idiomatic to me than informing against, but that change is not especially important here, it's the shift from "to" to "into" that adds the implication that he gave in)

Comment: I know that *pressure* has been verbed but I tend to feel that *press* works better.

Answer (score 50):

Actually, your example means what you want to say!  "He was pressured by the FBI to inform against his own friend," doesn't tell us whether on not he folded to the FBI's pressure.

Comment: +1 The most valuable part of this answer is the phrase "whether or not." The sentence does not tell us yes or no. It tells us pressure was brought to bear and why it was brought to bear, but it does not tell us anything about the outcome.

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned by TheAwesomeAtom, saying "He was pressured by the FBI to inform against his own friend" does not indicate he did inform against his friend.

However, to my ears, the sentence "The FBI pressured him to inform against his own friend" is even more ambiguous and perhaps better for your use.

If you wish to indicate he did inform, you could say "He was pressured by the FBI *into informing* against his own friend."

Comment: IMO passive vs. active voice has no impact on the ambiguousness of the sentence.  You make a great point about preposition choice making a big impact on meaning though. You could also indicate that he did inform using an active voice: "The FBI pressured him into informing against his own friend".

Answer (score 4):

While I agree with the other answer that the statement doesn't really say that the pressure was successful, you could make it clearer by saying

> The police *tried* to pressure him to inform against his friend.

"tried" without further qualification implies that they didn't succeed.

Comment: No, if they tried to pressure him, they failed even in that, let alone getting the information.

Comment: What's the difference between "didn't succeed" and "failed"?

Comment: I believe what Andrew was getting at is that the "tried" applies to *pressuring the guy*, not to *did he inform or not*. I mean, maybe the reason the FBI failed at the pressuring was that the guy caved at the first frown from the receptionist.

Comment: @Marthaª I think that's overly pedantic. Most would consider the interrogation itself to be pressure, so they succeeded at putting pressure on him. What matters is whether the pressure achieved the desired result.

Comment: @Barmar I agree that if the slightest pressure worked, that was still pressuring. But, to me one can fail to find anything that caused concern on the part of the target, and hence fail to apply pressure. I would suggest we still need into - the police tried to pressure him into informing against his friend.

Comment: @Bruce If I squeeze a lump of coal in my hands, I'm applying pressure to it. But unless I'm Superman, it won't have much effect. So I will succeed in pressuring it, but not in turning it to diamond.

Comment: Let's say they try to pressure me by threatening to tell my wife an embarrassing secret. But my wife already knows, so I'm not pressured. Their attempt to pressure me failed. Or this is indeed embarrassing, but I'd rather that my wife learned this than to inform on my friend. So they did pressure me, but pressuring me did not succeed.

Comment: I don't think anyone really cares whether the subject feels pressured, all that matters is whether the attempt achieved its goal (in the OP, informing on the friend). So we conflate them in casual language. Thus, "tried to pressure" is short for "tried to get him to inform by pressuring him".

Comment: @Barmar your analogy does not apply to my comment. Suppose instead that there are two hoses, one is connected to a balloon and the other is not. If I apply a pump to the one that is not connected then I fail even to apply pressure. If I apply a pump to the one that is connected then I apply pressure, but maybe the balloon is one of those very long thin ones, and fails to expand. I am not totally committed to the position regarding the popular semantics of the phrase, but the logic of the principle is fine.

Comment: That analogy hardly seems to apply, since you didn't even try to apply pressure to the unconnected balloon. The cops also aren't pressuing anyone outside the interrogation room, but they're not even under consideration.

Comment: I guess you're saying that you failed in trying because you forgot to connect the balloon in the first place. That would be like the cops failing to get the suspect into the interrogation room. We wouldn't say that they tried to pressure him in that case.

Comment: @Barmar The only reason that I can think of for why you think the analogy does not apply is that you are not understanding the suggestion I am making. The analogy was intended to clarify that. No, one did not insanely forget to connect the balloon. Rather, one did not realize that the hose you connected to was not in turn connected to the balloon. Try another one - if the police shoot into the room with the perpetrator the person was shot at. But, if they shoot into another room, then the person does not even notice, and arguably was not shot at, even though the police tried to shoot them.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand your suggestion. Are you saying that it makes a difference whether you say "pressure him to inform" or "pressure him into informing"?

Comment: @Barmar I am getting the expected "extended discussion warning" should we move to chat? (Yes, I am saying there is a difference as you suggest in your most recent comment).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139241/discussion-between-barmar-and-bruce).